# AS3 draw loader image in a BitmapData

Tags: image, actionscript-3, draw, loader, bitmapdata

When drawing an MovieClip into a BitmapData its works fine.
Yet, when trying to load a second MovieClip that include an external image uploaded by using a 'loader' the 'draw' does not work.

I have been uploading the image into the MovieClip using a 'loader' successfully, yet I can not draw the loader data into a BitmapData variable. This is extremely important as I need to export it.

Comment: Well, show your code and perhaps we can help spot the bug! :-)

Comment: You are 'uploading' it?!

Answer (score 0):

Draw the `loader.content` not the `loader`